# Email client not working properly on device?

Tags: android

i have made an application in which i first attach a file into my email and then start an intent to send email which i believe would be the default email client on the phone.

I have tested this application my HTC- Desire phone with android 2.1 and the attachment is properly being attached to the mail and the mail is being sent successfully.

But on another device which is Samsung galaxy s gt-19000, it is giving an error that attachment is too large.

The size of my attachment would not be exceeding 1 MB. 
what is going wrong over here?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the phones using the native mail applications? If yes, then I would guess that these have been programmed with a max size for attachments, which is something that you cannot change. Try attaching the attachment through in the email-client, and see if that works or not.

Comment: i am attaching them in the default email client. I start a Intent with the attachment uri set in Intent extra.. and whoever handles the Intent (which would be the email client inside the phone) handles my intent and sends the message...what could do more different than this?

Comment: As said in my first answer you should open the email client on the phone, attach a file > 1MB, and see if that works. I suspect it will give you the same error, which means that this is a restriction set by the native email client.